# Compiler errors for struct init in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, init

I have the following struct:

```
struct Person {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
   let assets: Double
}
```

To initialize a person, I would like to pass it a dictionary that contains the name and age, as well as info to calculate the assets:

```
public init(info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if let name = info["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }

        if let age = info["age"] as? Int {
            self.age = age
        }

        if let assets = info["assets"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
            calculateAssets(assets: assets)
        }
    }

    mutating func calculateAssets(assets: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.assets = 1+2+3.4  // really do this with info from the dictionary
    }
```

With this setup, I get two compiler errors:

1. 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
2. Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Following the compiler suggestions, I added a default value for each property, and changed them to be a `var`:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String = ""
    var age: Int = 0
    var assets: Double = 0.0

// init ...
}
```

And indeed, the compiler errors are gone.

But am I on the right track by making these corrections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your `init` function you *might* initialize the variables but you can't be sure, since the conditions of the `if` statements can be `false`. This is why the compiler is giving you the errors (also because you are trying to call `self.assets` in another function when the variable might still not be initialized - so you at least need to change this one to a `var`).

If you can't be sure that the values in the `info` dictionary are valid you should change your variables to `var`.

Now you have two choices:

- Give your variables a **default value** (like you did in your example)
- Declare your variables as `Optionals` (like suggested by @Özgür).

Your choice depends on what **makes more sense**. If your default values make sense for your situation and you can work with the variables having those values then I'd go with that.

Otherwise, you should go with the `Optionals`. `Optionals` obviously have the plus that you don't need to initialize them but then the con is that you'll need to implicitly or explicitly unwrap them later when you want to use them (using `?` or `!`).

If - *for whatever reason* - you can be sure that the values in the `info` dict are valid - you could also leave your `name` and `age` as constants (`let`) and just explicitly unwrap the dictionary values when you assign them:

```
self.name = info["name"] as! String

self.age = info["age"] as! Int
```

But as I said this would only work if `info["name"]` and `info["age"]` contain valid values, otherwise you will get a runtime exception. So the "default value" or "Optional" choices are your safe and clean options, whereas this is the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Got it. And even if the values are ok, I could get a runtime error if I make a typo: `info["naem"]`.  So I will just go with the default values or the `optionals`, I need to think about that.

Comment: And calling a function from `init` is ok to calculate a value?

Comment: Yes, as long as the variable you're setting is declared as a `var` with either a default value or as an Optional.

Comment: whenever  `info["name"] as! String` unwrap fails your app will crash so i dont advice that method.

Answer (score 1):

You got compiler error because your variables are `not inited` when you set them.(you define them as `inited`). That's why for second case when you `init` them to `nil` values, `error` is gone. For this conditions, Swift has `optionals`.Can be nil and a value at the same time. Check [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_optionals.htm). You can add `?` and that makes the variable `optional`.

```
struct Person {
    var name: String?
    var age: Int?
    var assets: Double?

// init ...
}
```

Comment: However, the name is required (a person must have a name), so can it still be an `optional` ?

Comment: it is not about that @Koen, you should check optionals for sure